# How can I run an async function using the schedule library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, schedule, discord.py

I'm writing a discord bot using discord.py rewrite, and I want to run a function every day at a certain time.  I'm not experienced with async functions at all and I can't figure out how to run one without using "await."  This is only a piece of my code which is why some things may not be defined.

```
async def send_channel():
    try:
        await active_channel.send('daily text here')
    except Exception:
        active_channel_id = None
        active_channel = None

async def timer():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        schedule.every().day.at("21:57").do(await send_channel())

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print("------")

    bot.loop.create_task(timer())
```

Using the `schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do()` function, I get this error when I put `await send_channel()` in the paramaters of `.do()`:

> self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
>   TypeError: the first argument must be callable

But when I don't use await, and I just have `send_channel()` as parameters, I get this error:

> RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'send_channel' was never awaited

I'm not super good at programming so if someone could try to dumb it down for me that would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Another option is to use [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html)'s AsyncIOScheduler, which works more naturally with async functions (such as `send_channel`). In your case, you can simply write something of the form:

```
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(send_channel, trigger=tr)
scheduler.start()
```

Where `tr` is a trigger object. You can use either `IntervalTrigger` with a 1-day interval and a start date at 21:57, or a `CronTrigger`.

Note that at the end of your program it is recommended to call `shutdown()` on the scheduler object.

Answer (score 9):

The built-in solution to this in [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) is to use the `discord.ext.tasks` extension.  This lets you register a task to be called repeatedly at a specific interval.  When the bots start, we'll delay the start of the loop until the target time, then run the task every 24 hours:

```
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def my_task():
    ...

@my_task.before_loop
async def before_my_task():
    hour = 21
    minute = 57
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    now = datetime.now()
    future = datetime.datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour, minute)
    if now.hour >= hour and now.minute > minute:
        future += timedelta(days=1)
    await asyncio.sleep((future-now).seconds)

my_task.start()
```

Answer (score 7):

What you're doing doesn't work because `do` takes a *function* (or another callable), but you're trying to `await` or call a function, and then pass it the result.

`await send_channel()` blocks until the send finishes and then gives you `None`, which isn't a function. `send_channel()` returns a coroutine that you can await later to do some work, and that isn't a function either.

If you passed it just `send_channel`, well, that is a function, but it's an `ascynio` coroutine function, which `schedule` won't know how to run.

---

Also, rather than trying to integrate `schedule` into the `asyncio` event loop, and figure out how to wrap async jobs up as `schedule` tasks and vice versa and so on, it would far easier to just give `schedule` its own thread.

[There's a FAQ entry on this](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-to-continuously-run-the-scheduler-without-blocking-the-main-thread):

> **How to continuously run the scheduler without blocking the main thread?**
>
> Run the scheduler in a separate thread. Mrwhick wrote up a nice solution in to this problem [here](https://github.com/mrhwick/schedule/blob/master/schedule/__init__.py) (look for run_continuously()).

The basic idea is simple. Change your `timer` function to this:

```
schedstop = threading.Event()
def timer():
    while not schedstop.is_set():
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(3)
schedthread = threading.Thread(target=timer)
schedthread.start()
```

Do this at the start of your program, before you even start your `asyncio` event loop.

At exit time, to stop the scheduler thread:

```
schedstop.set()
```

Now, to add a task, it doesn't matter whether you're in your top-level code, or in an async coroutine, or in a `scheduler` task, you just add it like this:

```
schedule.every().day.at("21:57").do(task)
```

---

Now, back to your first problem. The task you want to run isn't a normal function, it's an `asyncio` coroutine, which has to be run on the main thread as part of the main event loop.

But that's exactly what [`call_soon_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#concurrency-and-multithreading) is for. What you want to call is:

```
bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe(send_channel)
```

To ask `scheduler` to run that, you just pass `bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe` as the function and `send_channel` as the argument.

So, putting it all together:

```
schedule.every().day.at("21:57").do(
    bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe, send_channel)
```

Comment: Is the threading part necessary?  Because I couldn't get it to work and I'm not very familiar with threading (I know I should be.)

In terms of "schedule.every().day.at("21:57").do(
    bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe, send_channel)", that part wasn't working for me either.  I'm still getting an error, coroutine 'send_channel' was never awaited.  And I think the send_channel() function has to have async to work.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but I recently ran into the same issue. You can use [`run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) to schedule a coroutine to the event loop (rather than a callback):

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(async_function(), bot.loop)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is old question with many answers but I think there is better solution.

I think you can do it `@tasks.loop(time=datetime.time)`

It can be important to use correct `timezone`. Without `timezone` it will run with `UTC`.

```
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

# --- calculate correct time ---

#tz = datetime.timezone.utc                           # Europe/London (UTC)
#tz = datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(hours=2))  # Europe/Warsaw (CEST)(UTC+02:00)
tz = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo     # local timezone
print('timezone:', tz)

midnight = datetime.time(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=tz)
print('midnight:', midnight, midnight.tzinfo)

# --- loop ---

@tasks.loop(time=midnight)
async def send_channel():
    try:
        await active_channel.send('daily text here')
    except Exception:
        active_channel_id = None
        active_channel = None

# --- start loop ---

@bot.event
def on_ready()
    send_channel.start()   # without `await`

# ---

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

It can also use list `@tasks.loop(time=[time1, time2, ...])`

```
midnight = datetime.time(hour=0,  minute=0,  second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=tz)
noon     = datetime.time(hour=12, minute=0,  second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=tz)
at_21_57 = datetime.time(hour=21, minute=57, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=tz)

@tasks.loop(time=[midnight, noon, at_21_57])
async def send_channel():
     # ...code...
```

Answer (score 1):

Going through the very same problem I found a solution that mixes some of the previous solutions:

```py
import schedule
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(hours=24)
async def send_channel():
    pass
```

and later just before the main thread I define

```py
def event_starter(func):
    if not func.is_running():
        func.start()

schedstop = threading.Event()
def timer():
    while not schedstop.is_set():
        schedule.run_pending()
        sleep(1)
schedthread = threading.Thread(target=timer)
schedthread.start()
```

and finally, in the main thread:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":

    ...

    schedule.every().day.at('21:57:00').do(event_starter, send_channel)

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are encountering an issue because `schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do()` expects a callable function as an argument, but using `await` directly inside the `do()` function is causing a problem.

#### Solution:

You can use a lambda function to create a callable wrapper for your `send_channel` function.

**Corrected Code**

```py
import schedule
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

...

async def send_channel():
    try:
        await active_channel.send('daily text here')
    except Exception:
        active_channel_id = None
        active_channel = None

def schedule_send_channel():
    asyncio.ensure_future(send_channel())

async def timer():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(3)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print("------")

    # Schedule the task every day at 00:00
    schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(schedule_send_channel)

    bot.loop.create_task(timer())
...
```

#### Explanation:

1. Created a new function `schedule_send_channel`, which wraps the `send_channel` function in `asyncio.ensure_future()`.
2. Passed the `schedule_send_channel` function to `schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do()`. This way, it receives a callable function without any issues.
3. Removed `await` from the `do()` function, as it is not needed in this case.

##### Other suggestion

As pointed out by a few users, it is recommended to use in-built `tasks` and `tasks.loop`