# Scheduling an async function with the Schedule library. (Using discord.py rewrite)

Tags: python, asynchronous, schedule, discord.py

Firstly, I found a similar thread: [How can I run an async function using the schedule library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530012)

This did not help me, or the OP of the thread. I ended up with the same error as him, which he stated in a comment of the only answer.

My goal is to run a function (which must be async) every x seconds. (Set to seconds for testing purposes. The finished code will use days.)

My simplified code to try do this:

```
@bot.event
async def schedTest():
    print("Scheduled Message Here")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def announcements(ctx):
    schedule.every(1).seconds.do(
        bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe, schedTest)
```

After executing the command `announcements`,the result of this is nothing. No error or prints in the output.

This is not the same issue as the thread that this was marked as duplicate as. I am trying to get the schedule library to work, not asyncio.sleep. Sleep is not accurate over the duration of a week.