# Scheduling an async function using the Schedule library. (Using discord.py rewrite)

Tags: python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, schedule, discord.py

My last post got incorrectly marked as duplicate. **I am not trying to do asyncio.sleep, becuase it is too inaccurate over the space of weeks. I need the schedule library.**

I found a similar thread: [How can I run an async function using the schedule library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530012)
This did not help me, or the OP of the thread. I ended up with the same error as him, which he stated in a comment of the only answer.

My goal is to run a function (which must be async) every x seconds. (Set to seconds for testing purposes. The finished code will use days.)

My simplified code to try do this:

```
@bot.event
async def schedTest():
    print("Scheduled Message Here")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def announcements(ctx):
    schedule.every(1).seconds.do(
        bot.loop.call_soon_threadsafe, schedTest)
```

After executing the command `announcements`,the result of this is nothing. No error or prints in the output.

This is not the same issue as the thread that this was marked as duplicate as. I am trying to get the schedule library to work, not asyncio.sleep. Sleep is not accurate over the duration of a week.

If it isn't possible, could someone advise a way to do a scheduled function accurate to a few minutes over several weeks? As this is what I'm pretty much trying to achieve.

Comment: Any luck? I am chasing something similar

Comment: @peterNoges Unfortunately not. All I seem to remember is that async and schedule library don't really go together. An alternate method would be to use date/time references. I don't remember the name of it, but I think there's a library for date/time that works well for discord.py and such. Good luck on your endeavors mate!