# Is there a way to make a discord bot do something automatically (without message)?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been making a discord bot game recently, and want there to be daily events that players can join and compete in. But I want these events to appear automatically, without the client doing anything. I've thought about using the `cooldown()` function that discord offers and `time.sleep()`. But how would the bot know where to send the message?

Here's a short part if what I've tried:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import command, cooldown

@cooldown(1, 86400, '''What type should I use here?''')
async def '''what kind of function?'''():
   await '''What should I use to send'''("@everyone, a new event has appeared! **INFO**...")
```

Answer (score 0):

For this, you should use [tasks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html). There are examples in the docs.

Comment: [Here's an example running a task at the same time every day](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61180222/6779307)

Comment: But how would the bot know where to send the message?

Comment: You could use [fetch_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_channel) I strongly suggest you read the docs and get comfortable with them before trying to write a functional bot.

Comment: You could also use [get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel). Both have their use case and with the very little amount of info you've provided, I'm not sure which is best for you.