# Python shedule does not perform a function

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

My shedule script does not perform a function. I do everything as it should be, and the function does not call, so do not unmute and not print lol. When I put it instead of the print function, it was executed. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
def unmutetempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    print('lol')
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Wyciszony/a')
    if role in member.roles:
        unmuteembed = discord.Embed(
            title='Odciszono {}!'.format(member.name),
            color=28159,
            description='Czas wyciszenia się skończył.')

        ctx.channel.send(embed=unmuteembed)
        member.send(embed=unmuteembed)
        member.remove_roles(role)
        return schedule.CancelJob

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def tempmute(ctx,
                   member: discord.Member,
                   time: int,
                   *,
                   reason='Nie podano powodu'):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Wyciszony/a')

    if not role in member.roles:
        muteembed = discord.Embed(
            title='Wyciszono {}!'.format(member.name), color=28159)

        muteembed.add_field(name='Powód:', value=reason, inline=False)
        muteembed.add_field(
            name='Czas:', value='{}m'.format(time), inline=False)
        muteembed.add_field(
            name='Administrator:', value=ctx.author.mention, inline=False)

        await ctx.channel.send(embed=muteembed)
        await member.send(embed=muteembed)

        await member.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.message.delete()

        await schedule.every(time).seconds.do(
            unmutetempmute, ctx=ctx, member=member)
        return

    errorembed = discord.Embed(
        title='Błąd!',
        color=16711686,
        description='Użytkownik już jest wyciszony!')

    await ctx.channel.send(embed=errorembed)
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably **don't** want to use [`schedule`](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/) here, as it's not built with `asyncio` in mind, whereas `discord.py` is built on it. You *could* force it to work [like in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530012/how-can-i-run-an-async-function-using-the-schedule-library), but those solutions are pretty cumbersome since they try to work around the fact that `schedule` wasn't designed to be used with `asyncio`.

Instead, since this is a one-off delayed task, you can simply leverage basic `asyncio`:

```py
import asyncio


async def delayed_coro(seconds: int, coro):
    # Delays execution of the given coroutine by `seconds`
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
        await coro
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        coro.close()


# FIXED: This needs to be a coroutine!
async def unmutetempmute(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    print('lol')
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Wyciszony/a')
    if role in member.roles:
        unmuteembed = discord.Embed(
            title='Odciszono {}!'.format(member.name),
            color=28159,
            description='Czas wyciszenia się skończył.')

        await ctx.channel.send(embed=unmuteembed)
        await member.send(embed=unmuteembed)
        await member.remove_roles(role)


@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def tempmute(ctx,
                   member: discord.Member,
                   time: int,
                   *,
                   reason='Nie podano powodu'):
    role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='Wyciszony/a')
    if not role in member.roles:
        # create and send your embed
        # add muted role to user, etc.
        
        # You can also save the task returned by `create_task` if you want.
        await ctx.bot.loop.create_task(
            delay_coro(time, unmutetempmute(ctx, member)))
        return

    # errorembed stuff
```

### Step by Step

First, we create a small wrapper coroutine `delay_coro` that takes a number of seconds to wait before awaiting the given coroutine `coro`:

```py
async def delayed_coro(seconds: int, coro):
    # Delays execution of the given coroutine by `seconds`
    try:
        await asyncio.sleep(seconds)
        await coro
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        coro.close()
```

Then, in `tempmute`, instead of using `schedule.every(time).seconds`, we create a new task on the bot's event loop with `ctx.bot.loop.create_task`, passing in `unmutetempmute` wrapped within `delay_coro`:

```py
await ctx.bot.loop.create_task(
    delay_coro(time, unmutetempmute(ctx, member)))
```

Lastly, you forgot to make your `unmutetempmute` a coroutine and await the appropriate discord library calls, so I fixed that in the full example. Be sure to include those changes or it will not run.

---

#### A Little Extra

If at some point you find that you need to schedule something to run more than once, I recommend [the tasks extension](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html) that comes with `discord.py`; it provides helpers specifically for scheduling tasks in a loop when using `discord.py`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to let the schedule run as well.

```py
#  await schedule.every(time)...
schedule.run_pending()
```