# How can I 'await' an async function inside of Python's do function?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord.py

I'm trying to create a Discord bot using discord.py that will mention certain roles at certain times of the day. I'm currently using [schedule](https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to set the times at which these mentions will occur.

I'm running into a problem where I'm getting the following TypeError when trying to await the async function that sends the message with the mention:

```
File "c:\codebase\my-bot\scheduler.py", line 47, in set_schedules
    schedule.every().day.at("05:30").do(await ping_role, bot)
TypeError: object function can't be used in 'await' expression
```

Below is the code for my Discord bot (`bot.py`) and scheduler (`scheduler.py`).

**bot.py**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import os

from scheduler import run_continuously, set_schedules

token = "{redacted}"

description = "Test"

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', description=description, intents=intents)

BOT_CHANNELS = ('bot-spam', 'spam-bot')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Logged in as")
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print("------------")

    await set_schedules(bot)

    stop_run_continuously = run_continuously()

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot.run(token)
```

**scheduler.py**

```
import threading
import time

import schedule
import discord

def run_continuously(interval=1):
    cease_continuous_run = threading.Event()

    class ScheduleThread(threading.Thread):
        @classmethod
        def run(cls):
            while not cease_continuous_run.is_set():
                schedule.run_pending()
                time.sleep(interval)

    continuous_thread = ScheduleThread()
    continuous_thread.start()
    return cease_continuous_run

async def ping_role(bot):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        channels = [channel for channel in guild.channels if channel.name in ('bot-spam', 'spam-bot')]
        role = [role for role in guild.roles if role.name == "to_mention_role"][0]

        for channel in channels:
            await channel.send(f"{role.mention}: You have been mentioned!")

async def set_schedules(bot):
    schedule.every().day.at("5:30").do(await ping_role, bot)
```

I've also tried the following:

```
async def set_schedules(bot):
    schedule.every().day.at("5:30").do(ping_role, bot)
```

This gives `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ping__role' was never awaited self._run_job(job)`

```
def ping_role(bot):
    ...
    await ...
```

This gives `SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function`

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run an async function using the schedule library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530012/how-can-i-run-an-async-function-using-the-schedule-library)

Comment: II wouldn't recommend you using the `schedule` library as it is blocking ([What does "blocking" mean?](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean)), discord.py already has an extension for background tasks, take a look at the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html