# Discord schedule function at specific time every day can't pass ctx

Tags: python, discord

I want to run one of the functions every day at 0:00 but I keep getting errors if I use ctx param in the function I get this error:

```
test() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'
```

--- Function ---

```
async def test(ctx):
    #identical lines skipped
    category =  discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name = "test")
    #identical lines skipped
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=f'{ctx.author.avatar_url}?size=128')
    #other lines

schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(test)

async def task():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    client.loop.create_task(task())
```

But if I don't use the ctx param in the function I can't fetch the "test" category channel names because getting this error:

```
Missing "ctx" parameter
```

**UPDATE:**

```
async def test():
    chan = client.get_channel(833833396979236896)
    #identical lines skipped
    def not_pinned(msg):
        return not msg.pinned
    await chan.purge(limit=100, check=not_pinned)
    category =  client.get_channel(833732406140993536)
    #other lines

schedule.every().day.at("16:31").do(test)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
while True:
    loop.run_until_complete(schedule.run_pending())
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Now it runs the schedule for example at 16:31 but I get this error for channel purge (**this is really strange for me because if I don't use schedule then the test function works like a charm but I need a schedule which runs every day at the specific time**):

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'purge'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self explanatory, you are using ctx, but don't have ctx. If you really want to use ctx. I suggest starting the task in a command with the ctx, or you would have to change all references of ctx to the hard-coded channel.
Switching to hard-coded channel

```py
async def test(): #removed ctx
   #identical lines skipped
   category =  discord.utils.get(chan.guild.categories, name = "test")
   #identical lines skipped 
   embed.set_thumbnail(url=client.user.avatar_url_as(size=1024))
   #other lines
async def on_ready():
   asyncio.create_task(test())
```

We are simply removing ctx references and replacing it with constants, or hard-coded references.

### References:

- [`client.user`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client%20user#discord.Client.user)
- [`ClientUser.avatar_url_as`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=client%20user#discord.ClientUser.avatar_url_as) I noticed that you manually set the size, which is bad practice.
- [channel.guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel.guild)

Comment: Thanks, but `async def on_ready():
    asyncio.create_task(test())` runs the function immediatelly when the script is running and not at a specific time like `schedule.every().day.at("10:15").do(test)` , that just ignoring the schedule module

Comment: Then, you can can remove the asyncio.create_task, and just run the schedule.

Comment: I'm still trying to do the schedule thing but it's hard to figure out what's the problem for me. Can you check my updated question please?

Comment: You might need to use [APS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61168314/12451222) and [`client.fetch_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=fetch_channel#discord.Client.fetch_channel) instead of `get_channel`.